# Ember.js Accessing different json properties using RESTAdapter in the same file

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I have got a model like this:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
name: DS.attr('string'),
clothes: DS.attr()
});
```

And a file named "persons" like this

```
{
  "persons": [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "person1",
    "clothes": ["one trouser","another trouser"]
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "person2",
    "clothes": ["one trouser","another trouser"]
    }
   ]
}
```

I am calling it with:

```
return this.store.find('person');
```

Now, I would like to add for example information about who made the trousers to the json file:

```
"trousers": [
  {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "trouser1",
   "madeby": ["one worker","another worker"]
  },
  {
   "id": 2,
   "name": "trouser2",
   "clothes": ["one worker","another worker"]
  }
]
```

I am not asking how to make the relation between both, but how to have them in the same json file and call each one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about "side-loading". Ember Data can process more than one type of entity in the JSON.

Lets say you have a model for **Trouser**

```
App.Trouser = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  madeby: DS.attr()
});
```

If you were to return the JSON like so:

```
{
  "people": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "person1",
      "clothes": [1, 2]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "person2",
      "clothes": [1, 2]
    }
  ],
  "trousers": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "trouser1",
      "madeby": ["one worker","another worker"]
    },
    {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "trouser2",
     "clothes": ["one worker","another worker"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then a `store.find('person')` would see the `"trousers"` key and automatically load these into the store under the **Trouser** model. Similarly, if you had another model called **Pet**, you could add yet another key to the JSON, to load some pets automatically:

```
{
  "persons": [
    // ...
  ],
  "trousers": [
    // ...
  ],
  "pets": [
    // some pets here
  ]
}
```

Even if you have not created relationships between all these models, putting them in the JSON will load them into ember data's store.

Once they are in the store they will be retrievable with a standard lookup by *id*:

```
this.store.find('trouser', 1);
```

You could then wire up the relationship by doing the following:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  clothes: DS.hasMany('trouser') // <--
});
```

Comment: this.store.find('trouser', 1); is calling GET localhost/trousers instead of the same json file that persons

Comment: It returns  <DS.PromiseObject:ember663>, how could I access the name from there? .get('name') doesn't work

Comment: If I use .then it returns an [object Object], and If y try to see it using #each:  The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed {_id: 111, _label: undefined, _subscribers: }